# Getting error when import js file in .ts file

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, npm

when importing my file OLCesium.js from node_module olcs file getting error but when we import not showing and also showing error as you can see image.
[click here for image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9YwF.png)

[click here for image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iRzv.png)

[click here for image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrC6H.png)

while the file is available at that address.

Comment: you probably need to install the `tslib` for that library, and then import it without the `js`

Comment: I found an user maintained ts lib. It seems he had your exact same issue https://gist.github.com/thw0rted/c0c73335c9968d5e7b6dd18a43ef6c42

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli I install using  npm i --save olcs  but when we import then its showing error

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli why not showing file name in my suggestion only showing folder name

Comment: you have to --save-dev , ts content doesn't go to production, it only servers you while developing. Although I think this should not affect, can you try uninstalling this package and reinstalling on --save-dev?

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli I uninstall package and again install but it does not work

Comment: Try `npm i --save-dev @types/olcs` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'olcs/OLCesium';`      this error is showing

Comment: this is because the module does not belong to @types, but to cesium.

Another option is to copy paste what this guy has created and add the file manually yourself